# Creating view models in WP7 using MVVMLight v 4.0

Tags: mvvm, mvvm-light

I just started building a windows phone application and i am very much conscious about the    application's memory constraints. So my doubt is, is there any advantage for dynamic view models over static view models. I think if i create static view models, while the time of application launching the memory will be allocated for all my view models and  it may eventually increase my application's memory usage. How i can tackle this situation. I found in V 4.0. A SimpleIOC container is added along with the libraries, how i can make use of that. provide some samples or documentations that make me learn the technology easier.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have a highly complex model, the memory consumed by your view models will be trivial compared to the memory required to store your UI assets such as images, UI controls, views etc ...

Just create the view models in the most natural way. People do not use MVVMLight or IoC containers in order to reduce memory usage, they use them to help structure their code.

I would advise you to start simple, without any frameworks, and structure your code sensibly. I wrote a [blog post a while back that shows how to use MVVM for WP7](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/05/a-simple-windows-phone-7-mvvm-tombstoning-example/).